# How can an AP's guest wifi be separated from the local network

Tags: networking, router

My home network consists of a bridged ISP router, behind which is my Mikrotik main router. Connected via ethernet, there's an Asus router configured as access point providing normal wifi and guest wifi. I am wondering how the guest wifi internally is separated from the rest of the network. The main network is 192.168.0.0/24, and now that I try to understand my Mikrotik in terms of Routes, Address list, NAT rules, interfaces etc, I am wondering how alone in the AP settings, a separate network can be created that does not see the other devices. Isn't it also running in the same subnet? Or is the AP creating a new interface with rules that only allow outgoing connections via the gateway. Maybe someone can give me a hint how such rules could look like?

Comment: In this case, it likely isn't... it would provide client isolation from all the clients on the Asus router, but upstream it's just regular traffic, meaning everything between the Mikrotik and the Asus router.

Answer (score 0):

Each SSID is a separate interface, automatically. (A lot like VLANs.) They can be bridged to the same subnet, or they can have separate IP configuration. In RouterOS through Winbox, you would create a `Virtual` interface in order to add an additional SSID.

```
/interface/wireless/add name=wlan-guest master-interface=wlan2ghz ...
```

One way of implementing a guest Wi-Fi network is to *not* bridge the "guest SSID" wlan interface to the main LAN bridge, but to assign it a different IP subnet (e.g. 192.168.7.0/24 for guest Wi-Fi), then set up standard firewall rules (`/ip/firewall/filter`) blocking access from one subnet to the other.

Another option is to bridge both SSIDs into the main LAN but implement *bridge-level* filtering – on Linux (and on RouterOS) this is not limited to just MAC layer, the system can apply regular (IP and higher layer) iptables rules to bridged packets, if a special option is enabled. So you could have a firewall rule that drops all packets from wlan1_guest to 192.168.0.0/24.